# AnyLogic Resource Pool

Tags: resources, anylogic

I am modelling a machine that can process two different products. The ratio of space needed per product is 0.75:1 i.e. product A requires 75% of the spot required for product B. I wanted to draw from the resource pool using float values. That is each time product B is passed it draws one whole unit from the pool while if product A is passed then it should seize only 0.75 units. However it seems the resource pool can only take integer values. Is there any world around for this? Note that the machine is such that it can process both products at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since resource pools are made up of agents and you can't seize part of an agent the best option I can think of is to multiply the number of resources you have by 100 and then let the products seize 100x of what they normally would.

So if you currently had 10 units in the resource pool and products tried to seize 0.75 and 1 you will now have 1000 units in the resource pool and the products seize 75 and 100 units.

This should be a very simple workaround